# How postfix increment work when it meet addition(+) operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

First of all, I know the expressions talked about later has `side-effects`, and should not be used in production environment. I just want to understand `JavaScript` through them. All of them are tested under `Chrome`.

```
var a = 42;
var b = "42";
a + ++b; // result is 85
```

Here is my understanding of `a + ++b`,

The `Prefix Increment (++)` (precedence 15) has higher precedence than `Addition(+)` (precedence 13) according to [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `++b` could be parsed var `ToNumber(GetValue(expr))` to `43`, refer to [`12.5.7 Prefix Increment Operator`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator). Then the result of `a + 43` could be `85`.

However,

```
var a = 42;
var b = "42";
a++ + b; // "4242"
```

Why the result of `a++ + b` is `"4242"`?

I try to understand the result `"4242"`, it seems that the `a++` return `42` firstly, then for `42 + '42'`, the `42` will be `'42'` var `ToString()` firstly, refer to [`12.7.3 The Addition operator ( + )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus). then the result could be `"4242"`.

But it seems violate the rule: `Postfix increment` (precedence 16) higher than `Addition` (precedence 13)???

```
var a = 42;
var b = "42";
a +++b; // "4242"
```

How does the `a +++b;` be parsed?

Comment: `How does the a +++b; be parsed?` - what is `a` and `b` afterwards? that should give you enough clue to work it out

Comment: This is why I always put operations in brackets when the order of completion matters.

Comment: So your question is just "How postfix increment work" ?

Comment: *post* fix happens *post* - after.

Comment: Basically, `a +++b;` is parsed as `(a++) + b`

Answer (score 23):

Haha, tricky one!

Post-fix increment returns the same value and then increments the variable.
This is the default behaviour in every language I know.

So, when you do (**warning:** this is not a valid expression, it's just to show the idea):

```
42++ + "42"
```

What is really going on is:

1. First 42 is returned by the ++ operator
2. Then 42 is incremented to 43
3. Then 42 (the result value of the expression) is coerced into a string
4. Then the two operands are concatenated

---

**Edit #1:**

If you do:

```
var a = 42;
var b = "42";
a + b++; // result is 84
```

Test it!

**Edit #2:**

So, we conclude your question has nothing to do with operator precedence (:

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference in post and pre increment in javascript then other languages. That is these operators can be seperated by a single space from the operand. For example:

```
var a = 42;
++ a;
```

Notice the space between ++ and a, this also works with `a ++` 
so when javascript start parsing statements it takes operand or operator and store it in its stack and find any chance to use that. I hope you know how languages parse statements, from left to right or right to left. Javascript parse it from left to right.
 So, when you wrote `a +++b` it started parsing from left,

> Found a: push a in stack; stack: [a] 
>     Found +: push + in stack; stack: [a, +] 
>  
>     Found +: pop + and a from stack and apply operand and push the
>     result on stack (Now the stack only has a in memory, not a++ because
>     of post increment); stack [a] 
>     Found +: push on stack; stack: [a, +] 
>     Found b: pop + and a from stack, apply operand and push the result on stack; stack: [b]

No more operands or operators, so it gives the result which is `a+b` and also increment a after it as a result of post increment on a, 
if you wanted to increment b before adding, you can try this:

```
a + ++b
```

this will seprate + from ++, now javascript knows where to apply increment.

Answer (score 7):

Of course the increment/decrement operators - being **unary** operators - have precedence over the `+` (addition/concatenation) **binary** operator, but I think the intersting issue here is **coercion**. Let me explain:

> Why the result of a++ + b is 4242?

(`a` is a number 42 and `b` is a string '42')

It's because when you apply the `increment` operator to a string with a number value ('42') the result is coerced to a number (42).

So now we are left with an expression `number + string` (42 + '42') : In this case the `+` operator will *concatenate* (coercing the number 42 into the string '42' and resulting in the string '4242').

On the other hand: in the first example `a + ++b` ( `a` is number 42 and `b` is  string '42') - `b` will be coerced into a number after the increment leaving us with `number + number` (42 + 43) - so the `+` operator will do an `addition` instead of concatenation (42 + 43 = 85)

Regarding the next question:

> How does the a +++b; be parsed?

Since it is legal to separate the variable and the increment opeator with a space so the parser will look at `a +++b` and first see `a++`.

Also, since the `+` operator doesn't require spaces between both of its operands, the parser will separate the operands `a++` and `b` correctly with the `+` operator. So `a +++b;` will be parsed as `a++ + b`

Comment: Could I consider `a +++b;` same as `a++ + b;`?

Comment: Yes. It is legal to separate the variable and the increment opeator with a space. So a++ === a ++. In addition: the `+` operator *doesn't* require spaces between both operands and the `+` operator. So, yes, `a +++b` is the same as `a++ +b`

Comment: So the `operator associativity` of postfix increment is `n/a` could also affect the parsing of `a +++b;`? or not?

Comment: By default the parser will go from left to right. Of coarse you could change this if you were to add brackets in the expression like `a +(++b)` - in which case `b` would be preincremented

Answer (score 5):

@zangw there is is nothing like ++ has higher precedence than +. ++b is an pre increment operator and + is an arithmetic .++b means first change the value of an operand and then use it contradicting to a++. ++ comes always with one operand and + comes between two operands and the later is an experession. hope you got it?

Answer (score 3):

Good question, check this [ecma standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 12.7.3.1 (step 11)

```
11. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
   a. Let lstr be ToString(lprim).
   b. ReturnIfAbrupt(lstr).
   c. Let rstr be ToString(rprim).
   d. ReturnIfAbrupt(rstr).
   e. Return the String that is the result of concatenating lstr and rstr
```

if either of the operator is `string` then both are converted to string and then concatenation is performed.

Answer (score 3):

This actually has nothing to do with operator precedence; it is related to the lexing/parsing, which happens long before any concept like operator precedence is even applied.
The lexer for JavaScript, like many other languages, is "greedy", meaning given the choice of "+" and "++" will always chose the longer symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question, but here is the answer :).

```
    var a = 42;
    var b = "42";
    console.log(a +++b); // "4242" 
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log('A is 43 now... so postfix on A, then + B');
```

Answer (score 2):

The **post** part of the name comes not just from the physical presence of the operator(before the operand or after the operand), but from when the variable is actually updated.

Postfix increment is defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment) as:

> [The increment (++) operator,] If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then
>   it returns the value before incrementing.

Hence, it returns the value to the concatenation and then increments the variable. That is, the post-incremented variable is updated after returning the original value to the addition operation.

The answer to your question lies in realising when the variable is updated.

The operator precedence makes sense because the postfix is still evaluated first and then the 
addition is performed. However, the variable of the postfix is not updated until the value is returned to the addition. Hence, the result is "4242".